# Attribute with the same code already exists when add Custom Customer Attribute from Controller

Tags: magento2, controllers, customer-attribute

i try following this [tutorial](http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-make-customer-attribute.html) to add new customer attribute, the tutorial run the function at `InstallData.php`. I'm trying to run the function from controller and i got the following error:

```
"Attribute with the same code already exists.";i:1;s:6637:"#0 /var/www/project/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php(400)
```

here's my controller code:

```
    use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

    class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {
      protected $idListing;

      public function __construct(
            CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
            AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
            ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
            ModuleContextInterface $contextt,
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
        ) {
            $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
            $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory; 
            $this->setup =$setup;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

      private function saveAttribute(){
        $context = $this->contextt;
        $setup = $this->setup; 
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'test1234', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'test',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'test1234')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);
        try {
          $attribute->save();
          echo "success";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          print_r($e->getMessage());
        }
        exit;
      }

      public function execute()
      {

         $this->saveAttribute();
         exit;
      }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve it? I am stuck at exactly the same problem ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you run the function to save to eav attribute, you can try clean magento cache programmatically  like this:

```
public function __construct( 
   \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
   \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
) { 
   $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
   $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool; 
}

private function cleanCache(){
   $types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
   foreach ($types as $type) {
     $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
   }
   foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
     $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom customer attributes as below:

> /public_html/development/app/code/Barcode/Unique/Setup/InstallData.php

```
namespace Barcode\Unique\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration; // It can be skipped
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

private $customerSetupFactory;

public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory) {
     $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);

    $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "barcode_unique");
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "barcode_unique",  array(
        "type"     => "varchar",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Barcode",
        "input"    => "text",
        "source"   => "",
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => false,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => ""

    ));
        $barcode_unique   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "barcode_unique");

    $barcode_unique = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'barcode_unique');
      $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $barcode_unique->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 1002);
$barcode_unique->save();
$installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

You will have to create module and call this field in phtml file like:

> /public_html/development/app/code/Barcode/Unique/view/frontend/templates/additionalinfocustomer.phtml

Comment: still got the same error

Comment: Did you create the module? and you need clean,flush.upgrade and compile. I hope you did? and which version you are using? I just tested above code and its working fine(Magento 2.1.3). Above code is displaying field in admin and front. Clean cache manually from pub/static and other cached folders and deploy.

Comment: yes it will work if i clean,flush.upgrade and compile, the problem is i'm running this function in controller not in InstallData, i cant run clean,flush.upgrade and compile everytime i call the controller to run this function

Comment: According to magento doc, we should create new fields with installData and I havent try it with controller.